# suffix package, cannot redefine a suffixed macro

Tags: macros, package-writing, starred-version

I have two local packages `A` and `B`. 
Package `B` is used occasionally to override macros defined in package `A`.

Package `A` defines a macro and, using the `suffix` package, also defines a starred version of the macro.

Package `B` overrides both macros (unstarred and starred) from `A`. The redefinition of the unstarred macro works, but the redefinition of the starred version is be ignored; the `*` is taken as text.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{Plain Hello #1}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\mymacro*[1]{Starred Hello #1}
\begin{document}

\mymacro{world}

\mymacro*{world}

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\mymacro}[1]{Plain New Hello #1}
\WithSuffix\renewcommand\mymacro*[1]{Starred New Hello #1}

\mymacro{world}

\mymacro*{world}
\end{document}
```

The result of the code is here.  The last call to `\mymacro*{world}` sees the `*` as text and not the redefined macro. How can I redefine the starred version?

[image: resulting document:]

Comment: Perhaps, it’s worth asking the package author about this. Even if it’s not a bug it might be a lacking feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick look suggests that on the first definition, `\WithSuffix` records the fact that `\mymacro` has been modified to take a suffix. So when you do the second `\WithSuffix`, it does not try to alter `\mymacro`. However, because you've redefined `\mymacro`, the necessary internal code has been removed and so things will not work.

I think the only sensible approach is to alter the macro that `suffix` has used to store `\mymacro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{Plain Hello #1}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\mymacro*[1]{Starred Hello #1}
\begin{document}

\mymacro{world}

\mymacro*{world}

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter
  {\csname\NoSuffixName\mymacro\endcsname}[1]{Plain New Hello #1}
\WithSuffix\renewcommand\mymacro*[1]{Starred New Hello #1}

\mymacro{world}

\mymacro*{world}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I looked at the suffix package code and I doubt I ever would have seen the solution. Your code is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Instead of `\csname WSF:\string\mymacro\endcsname`, you can also use `\csname\NoSuffixName\mymacro\endcsname`. This is more robust.

Comment: @mhp Edited in: I just picked up the format from `\tracingall` :-)